# What could be the reason for error message "Invalid XSL format (or) file name" output by WMIC on retrieving day of week?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2
The same XSL files from the `Windows\SYSWOW64` exist in the directory `Windows\System32`.

The batch command:

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2-4 delims=," %A in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:csv') do set DAYNUMBER=%A
```

The error in German:

> Ungültiges XSL-Format (oder) Dateiname.

The error in English:

> Invalid XSL format (or) file name.

Comments: This is a production server without Windows updates.

What could be the reason for this error message output by WMIC on retrieving day of week?

Answer (score 2):

`wmic` of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 searches for the `*.xsl` file according to specified format like `csv` first in directory

> %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem

But this directory does not contain anymore `*.xsl` files on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2. Even if there is the appropriate `*.xsl` file in this directory, it is first ignored by `wmic`.

Next `wmic` searches for the appropriate `*.xsl` file in directory

> %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\**language-country**

according to language and country of the operating system. For example if an English Windows 7 is used and `/format:csv` is used then `wmic` searches and also finds first

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\en-US\csv.xsl
```

But if **Format** as defined in the **Region and Language** settings in Windows **Control Panel** on tab **Formats** is set to a different language and country than the operating system language and country like **German (Austria)**, `wmic` ignores the found `csv.xsl` in the operating system language and country subdirectory and searches next for `*.xsl` file in the specified format language and country subdirectory which is for this example

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\de-AT\csv.xsl
```

But even with using a German Windows 7 or German Windows Server 2008 R2 there is no such directory as the operating system is available only in `de-DE`.

Last `wmic` searches again in directory

> %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem

for the `*.xsl` file where it was found on Windows XP. But on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 this directory does not contain anymore `*.xsl` files as being now language dependent.

There are at least 4 solutions for this problem:

1. **Format** on tab **Formats** in **Region and Language** settings is set to same language and country as the operating system.

   This would mean on an English Windows 7 used in Austria to change **Format** from **German (Austria)** to **English (United States)**. Or on a German Windows Server 2008 R2 used in Austria to change **Format** from **German (Austria)** to **German (Germany)**.

   **Note:** The date/time formats changes, too. There are even differences between **German (Austria)** and **German (Germany)** although they can't be seen easily like *Jänner* for Austria versus *Januar* for Germany in long date format. And using **English (United States)** on a Windows computer used in Austria or Germany is really not advisable.
2. The `*.xls` files in the existing **language-country** subdirectory of the operating system are copied with administrator privileges to `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem` for 64-bit `wmic` on Windows x64 and 32-bit `wmic` on Windows x86 and also to `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\wbem` for 32-bit `wmic` on Windows x64.

   **Note**: This solution is not recommended as it could happen in future that a Windows update updates one or more of the `*.xsl` files resulting in having older `*.xsl` files in `wbem` directory still used after the update.

   For the example with English Windows 7 and German (Austria) set as format the search behavior of `wmic` is as follows:
   `wmic` first finds `csv.xsl` in `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem` and first ignores it. Next it finds the file in `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\en-US` and ignores also this file. Then it searches for the file in `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\de-AT`, but this directory does not exist at all. And last it finds again the file in `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem` and now reads it.
3. The format is specified with full path and file name enclosed in double quotes. Then `wmic` must not search around for the file.

   This would mean for an English Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 to use

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\en-US\csv.xsl"
   ```

   And for German Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 to use

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\de-DE\csv.xsl"
   ```

   **Note:** The double quotes around file name are important as otherwise the execution could fail with the error message

   > Invalid command.

   I don't know why the format specification without double quotes around full file name fails although the full file name does not contain a space. Could be a command line parameter parsing error of `wmic`.
4. The current directory is set to the **language-country** subdirectory in directory `wbem` really existing and format is specified with file name and with file extension, but without path.

   Example for German Windows Server 2008 R2:

   ```
   cd /D "%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\de-DE"
   ..\wmic.exe Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:csv.xsl
   ```

   The file extension is important as otherwise the file is again not found.

The file search behavior was found out by me using free tool [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) from Sysinternals (Microsoft).

But there is a format independent solution for this specific task by not using CSV format at all.

---

There is absolutely no need for `/Format:csv` in the command line to get day of week with `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday, `2` for Tuesday, ..., `6` for Saturday.

Use in the batch file:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1" %%W in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path win32_localtime get DayOfWeek') do (
    set "DAYNUMBER=%%W"
    goto ProcessWeekDay
)
:ProcessWeekDay
echo Day of week is: %DAYNUMBER%
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic path win32_localtime get /?`

Run from within a command prompt window `wmic path win32_localtime get DayOfWeek` and you can see which lines this command outputs:

```
DayOfWeek  
1
```

Now it is more clear why command **FOR** should skip the first line and assign value from second line to the environment variable. Note: There are trailing spaces after `DayOfWeek` and value `1`.

What can't bee seen is that **WMIC** outputs the 3 lines in Unicode encoding UTF-16 Little Endian with BOM (byte order mark). Command **FOR** has some problems to parse UTF-16 encoded output and interprets the third line wrong with carriage return as string read from the blank line. Therefore it is necessary to exit the loop after having the value of day of week from second line assigned to the environment variable to avoid clearing the environment variable immediately after having it just set.

Another method suggested by [DavidPostill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536342/davidpostill) uses Windows standard console application **FINDSTR** to filter out the blank line at bottom of Unicode output of **WMIC**.

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1" %%W in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path win32_localtime get DayOfWeek ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /V "^$"') do set "DAYNUMBER=%%W"
echo Day of week is: %DAYNUMBER%
```

One more variant which uses **FINDSTR** to get processed by **FOR** just lines starting with a digit in range 0-6.

```
@echo off
for /F %%W in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path win32_localtime get DayOfWeek ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[0-6]"') do set "DAYNUMBER=%%W"
echo Day of week is: %DAYNUMBER%
```

The line with the value has additionally 10 trailing spaces which is the reason why the regular expression `^[0-6]$` would not work, but `^[0-6].*$` or more easily `^[0-6]` works.
**FOR** removes those trailing spaces as the default delimiters are the space character and the horizontal tab character on splitting up the line to tokens.

And working is also:

```
@echo off
for /F %%W in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path win32_localtime get DayOfWeek ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\more.com +1') do set "DAYNUMBER=%%W"
echo Day of week is: %DAYNUMBER%
```

The standard Windows console application **MORE** is used for conversion of Unicode output (2 bytes per character) to OEM (1 byte per character) with skipping first line already by **MORE**.

Well, in real **WMIC** outputs just 2 lines and the third blank line is the result of a not good coded Unicode to OEM conversion by Windows command interpreter.

Comment: You can also pipe the `wmic` output to `findstr` to remove the blank lines: `'%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path win32_localtime get DayOfWeek ^| findstr /r /v "^$"'` Then you don't need the `goto` and label.

Comment: @DavidPostill It is indeed a very good idea to filter the blank lines with `findstr`. It makes the code for this task a little bit slower. But if the number of output lines is not fixed, filtering output of `wmic` with `findstr` is definitely better than what I used before (redirect wmic output to a file, `type` file within `for`, delete the file after the loop). Many thanks for this very useful filter method. BTW: In my batch file used as template for this answer I have `if %%W == 6 goto WeeklyCleanup` and therefore don't have an extra label after the loop.

Comment: You're welcome :) I don't worry about speed for such short batch files so I always use `wmic` with `findstr`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

Setting of region and language:
de/Österreich
changed to
de/Deutschland

the 2nd solution was to define the exact path of the csv file
WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /Format:%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\de-de\csv.xls