# Filter results in batch script for user printer selection

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a script to allow users to temporarily set the default windows printer to a selected printer (PDF, XPS, OneNote) before printing and then automatically set the default back to the original printer after a specified time.

I have managed to incorporate elements of many different examples to get to the stage where the script is functioning, although it is creating an extra entry at the start and end of the list.
I would like to filter the list of printers the user is shown to just ones from the appropriate list (e.g. PDF, XPS, OneNote).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    
    FOR /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%A in (
      'wmic printer where "default=True" get name /value'
      ) do SET DefaultPrinter=%%A
    
    ECHO.
    ECHO ==============================================================
    ECHO Current Default Printer
    ECHO ==============================================================
    ECHO.
    ECHO Default Printer = %DefaultPrinter%
    ECHO.
    
    pause
    Cls
    
    ECHO ==============================================================
    ECHO Processing locally installed printers
    ECHO ==============================================================
    
    ::build "array" of printers
    set printerCnt=0
    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('wmic printer get Name') do (
      set /a printerCnt+=1
      set "printer!printerCnt!=%%F"
    )
    
    
    ::print menu
    for /l %%N in (1 1 %printerCnt%) do echo %%N - !printer%%N!
    echo(
    
    
    :get selection
    set selection=
    set /p "selection=Enter a printer number: "
    echo You picked !printer%selection%!
    set NewPrinter=!printer%selection%!
    
    ::trim selection
    set str=%NewPrinter%
    for /l %%a in (1,1,31) do if "!str:~-1!"==" " set str=!str:~0,-1!

    
    RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%str%"
    
    TIMEOUT 10
    
    RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%DefaultPrinter%"
```

**[Edit /]**
I have included the code I ended up using. This was based on the answer provided by @Hackoo and I incorporated elements provided by @Magoo also. There is probably a more elegant way to write this code but I am new to this so laid it out as I understood it.

```
@echo off
Mode 70,30 & color F0
Title Healthmail Printer Selection
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%A in (
  'wmic printer where "default=True" get name /value'
  ) do SET "DefaultPrinter=%%A"

ECHO.
ECHO    ==============================================================
ECHO                    Current Default Printer
ECHO    ==============================================================
ECHO.
ECHO           Default Printer = [%DefaultPrinter%]
ECHO.
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NoBreak>nul

Cls
ECHO.
ECHO    ==============================================================
ECHO                        Available Printers
ECHO    ==============================================================
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::build "array" of printers
Set "FilterList=%Temp%\FilterList.txt"
REM Create a file to filter just for PDF printers
>"%FilterList%" (
    echo PDF
)

set printerCnt=0
@for /f "delims=" %%a in (
'wmic printer get Name ^|findstr /G:%FilterList%"'
) do ( 
    @for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set /a printerCnt+=1
        set "printer!printerCnt!=%%~nb"
    )
)

::If no printers have been found, go to filterlistlong
:zerofilterprinters
IF !printerCnt!==0 GOTO :filterlistlong
IF !printerCnt! gtr 0 GOTO :printmenu


:filterlistlong
Set "FilterListLong=%Temp%\FilterListLong.txt"
REM Create a file to filter with each word like XPS,OneNote and PDF
>"%FilterListLong%" (
    echo PDF
    echo XPS
    echo OneNote
)

set printerCnt=0
@for /f "delims=" %%a in (
'wmic printer get Name ^|findstr /G:%FilterListLong%"'
) do ( 
    @for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set /a printerCnt+=1
        set "printer!printerCnt!=%%~nb"
    )
)


:printmenu
SET "choices="
for /l %%N in (1 1 %printerCnt%) do SET "choices=!choices!%%N"&SET "printer%%N=!printer%%N!"&IF %printercnt% gtr 1 echo %%N - !printer%%N!
echo(


:get selection
:: If no available options, exit
IF NOT DEFINED choices GOTO :EOF 

:: If only 1 option, auto-select that
IF %choices%==1 SET /a selection=1&GOTO autoselect

choice /c %choices% /m "Enter a printer number: "
set selection=%ERRORLEVEL%
:: Error condition
IF %selection% gtr %printercnt% GOTO :EOF 
:: Control-C
IF %selection% equ 0 GOTO :EOF 

cls
ECHO    ==============================================================
ECHO                 You selected: !printer%selection%!
ECHO    ==============================================================
echo.
echo. Please proceed to print document.
echo.
echo. This window will close automatically in 30 seconds.
::GOTO :setprinter

:autoselect
set NewPrinter=!printer%selection%!
cls
ECHO    ==============================================================
ECHO              Printer selected: !printer%selection%!
ECHO    ==============================================================
echo.
echo. Please proceed to print document.
echo.
echo. This window will close automatically in 10 seconds.

:setprinter
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%NewPrinter%"
TIMEOUT /T 10 /nobreak > NUL
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%DefaultPrinter%"

GOTO :EOF

If Exist "%FilterList%" Del "%FilterList%"
If Exist "%FilterListLong%" Del "%FilterListLong%"
```

Comment: If you want to filter your list of enumerated printers, you should be able to incorporate that directly into your `WMIC` command. For example: `… Printer Where "Name Like 'OneNote%%' Or Name Like '%%PDF%%' Or Name Like '%%XPS%%'" Get …`. I haven't incorporated that directly into my answer, _(or its recently added additional edit, to cater for both Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2)_, but it shouldn't cause you a problem should you wish to make that adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of WMIC is unicode !

The trailing `<CR>` can be removed by passing the value through another FOR /F loop.

This also removes the phantom "blank" line (actually a `<CR>`) and in this case you don't need to use the `Trim` function !

```bat
@echo off
Mode 70,30 & color 0A
Title Filter results in batch script for user printer selection
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%A in (
  'wmic printer where "default=True" get name /value'
  ) do SET "DefaultPrinter=%%A"

ECHO.
ECHO    ==============================================================
ECHO                    Current Default Printer
ECHO    ==============================================================
ECHO.
ECHO           Default Printer = [%DefaultPrinter%]
ECHO.
TIMEOUT /T 3 /NoBreak>nul

Cls
ECHO.
ECHO    ==============================================================
ECHO              Processing locally installed printers
ECHO    ==============================================================
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::build "array" of printers
REM We Ignore printer begin with Micro or Fax in the name
Set "FilterList=%Temp%\FilterList.txt"
REM We create a file to filter with each word like XPS,OneNote and PDF
>"%FilterList%" (
    echo XPS
    echo OneNote
    echo PDF
)

set printerCnt=0
@for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (
'wmic printer get Name ^|findstr /G:%FilterList%"'
) do ( 
    @for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set /a printerCnt+=1
        set "printer!printerCnt!=%%~nb"
    )
)

::print menu
for /l %%N in (1 1 %printerCnt%) do echo    [%%N] - [!printer%%N!]
echo    ==============================================================

:get selection
set selection=
set /p "selection=Enter a printer number: "
set "NewPrinter=!printer%selection%!"
echo. You picked [%NewPrinter%]

RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%NewPrinter%"
TIMEOUT /T 10
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%DefaultPrinter%"

If Exist "%FilterList%" Del "%FilterList%"
```

Comment: I didn't know you were able to format the window like that so thanks for showing me how to achieve the clean look. 
Any idea about how to filter the results to only display printer names which contain PDF, XPS or OneNote?

Comment: Just give another try with the last edited code with filter list !

Comment: That's great, thanks for the help with this. I just had to remove the skip=1 which I think was an artefact from the last version.

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct as I initially began testing your answer with end-users yesterday. I have since incorporated a lot of logic from the answer provided by @Magoo also so I am very grateful for this input also.

Answer (score 1):

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "printfilter=%1"

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims==" %%A in (
  'wmic printer where "default=True" get name /value'
  ) do SET DefaultPrinter=%%A

ECHO.
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO Current Default Printer
ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO.
ECHO Default Printer = %DefaultPrinter%
ECHO.

pause
Cls

ECHO ==============================================================
ECHO Processing locally installed printers
ECHO ==============================================================

::build "array" of printers
set printerCnt=0
for /f "skip=1eol=: delims=" %%F in ('wmic printer get Name') do (
  set /a printerCnt+=1
  set "printer!printerCnt!=%%F"
  IF DEFINED printfilter ECHO %%F|FIND /i "%printfilter%" >nul&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET /a printercnt-=1
)
iF NOT DEFINED printfilter (
 set "printer%printerCnt%="
 SET /a printercnt-=1
)


::print menu
SET "choices="
for /l %%N in (1 1 %printerCnt%) do SET "choices=!choices!%%N"&SET "printer%%N=!printer%%N:~0,-1!"&IF %printercnt% gtr 1 echo %%N - !printer%%N!
echo(


:get selection

:: If no available options, exit
IF NOT DEFINED choices GOTO :EOF 

:: If only 1 option, auto-select that

IF %choices%==1 SET /a selection=1&GOTO autoselect

choice /c %choices% /m "Enter a printer number: "
set selection=%ERRORLEVEL%
:: Error condition
IF %selection% gtr %printercnt% GOTO :EOF 
:: Control-C
IF %selection% equ 0 GOTO :EOF 
echo You picked !printer%selection%!
:autoselect
set NewPrinter=!printer%selection%!

::trim selection
set str=%NewPrinter%
for /l %%a in (1,1,31) do if "!str:~-1!"==" " set str=!str:~0,-1!

ECHO RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%str%"

ECHO TIMEOUT 10

ECHO RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%DefaultPrinter%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Amusing...

First, to specify the filter, simply append an appropriate string `(PDF, XPS, OneNote)` to the batchname as a parameter. Omitting this selects ALL.

First step is to add the `skip=1` to the `for /f ... %%F...` so that the `Name` line from the report is skipped.

Next, if the filter is invoked, detect whether the printername includes the filter string.  If it does NOT, then back up the printer-counter.

Having built the array, noting that the last (bogus) entry will have been recorded UNLESS the filter is invoked, clear the last (bogus) entry and back up the counter.

The point with `WMIC` output is that it's not only Unicode, but it has a line-terminator of `<CR><CR><LF>` instead of `<CR><LF>`. The text values stored in the array each have a terminal `<CR>`. Hence the bogus last entry.

So, for each entry passing the filter, build a string of the options allowed into `choices`, and remove the last character from the printer name string and show it.

Now if there are no choices, exit (or something else).

If there's only one choice, auto-select it (and don't show the selection-list) Otherwise use `choice` to select the printers from the list.

You'd need to add to the list of choices to allow selection of printers beyond #9.

and I chose to simply `echo` the `rundll32`s and timeout for testing.

Comment: Thanks, I have very little experience with batch files so your code was a great help. I never thought about error handling so it was very beneficial to have that added. Not having to press enter after the selection is also a nice touch.
I was able to hard code the filter to a particular printer  - SET "printfilter=Microsoft XPS Class Driver" - but is there a way to set it to something such as *PDF*, *XPS*, *OneNote*?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just enumerate the printers once, and get rid of much of the unnecessary screen output:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "SysDir=%SystemRoot%\System32"
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Printer[) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "DefaultPrinter="
For /F "Tokens=1-3,* Delims=[,]" %%G In ('%SysDir%\wbem\WMIC.exe Printer Get
 Default^, Name /Format:CSV 2^>NUL ^| %SysDir%\findstr.exe "E\>" ^|
 %SysDir%\find.exe /V /N ""') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%K In ("%%J") Do (
    Echo([%%G] %%K
    If "%%I" == "TRUE" Set "DefaultPrinter=%%K"
    Set "Printer[%%G]=%%K")
If Not Defined Printer[1] (Echo No printers found.
    Echo Press any key to end . . .
    GoTo :EOF)
Echo(
(Set DefaultPrinter) 2>NUL || Echo No default printer found.

:Selection
Echo(
Set "UserPrinter="
Set /P "UserPrinter=Enter the number for your preferred printer>"
Set "UserPrinter=%UserPrinter:"=%"
Set Printer[ | %SysDir%\findstr.exe /B /L "Printer[%UserPrinter%]=" 1>NUL || (
    GoTo Selection)
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("!Printer[%UserPrinter%]!") Do EndLocal & Set "UserPrinter=%%~G"
Echo(
Echo You Selected %UserPrinter%
%SysDir%\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL

%SysDir%\rundll32.exe %SysDir%\printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%UserPrinter%"
%SysDir%\timeout.exe /T 10
%SysDir%\rundll32.exe %SysDir%\printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%DefaultPrinter%"
```

**[EDIT /]**

If you really do need to support [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7), and [windows-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2), and you cannot guarantee that the XSL files have been copied up a level on the target machine, then it should still possible. Although it looks like a lot of extra lines, the following example should not seriously impact your script speed, other than the extra call to the relatively slow `WMIC.exe`, *(your example, as well as the other currently submitted answers, already use more than one `WMIC` command)*.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "SysDir=%SystemRoot%\System32"
%SysDir%\wbem\WMIC.exe OS Where "Version Like '6.1%%'" Get Version 2>NUL ^
 | %SysDir%\find.exe "6.1" 1>NUL && Call :GetXSLDir
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Printer[) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "DefaultPrinter="
For /F "Tokens=1-3,* Delims=[,]" %%G In ('%SysDir%\wbem\WMIC.exe Printer Get
 Default^, Name /Format:"%XSLDir%csv.xsl" 2^>NUL ^| %SysDir%\findstr.exe "E\>"
 ^| %SysDir%\find.exe /V /N ""') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%K In ("%%J") Do (
    Echo([%%G] %%K
    If "%%I" == "TRUE" Set "DefaultPrinter=%%K"
    Set "Printer[%%G]=%%K")
If Not Defined Printer[1] (Echo No printers found.
    Echo Press any key to end . . .
    GoTo :EOF)
Echo(
(Set DefaultPrinter) 2>NUL || Echo No default printer found.

:Selection
Echo(
Set "UserPrinter="
Set /P "UserPrinter=Enter the number for your preferred printer>"
Set "UserPrinter=%UserPrinter:"=%"
Set Printer[ | %SysDir%\findstr.exe /B /L "Printer[%UserPrinter%]=" 1>NUL || (
    GoTo Selection)
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("!Printer[%UserPrinter%]!") Do EndLocal & Set "UserPrinter=%%~G"
Echo(
Echo You Selected %UserPrinter%
%SysDir%\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL

%SysDir%\rundll32.exe %SysDir%\printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%UserPrinter%"
%SysDir%\timeout.exe /T 10
%SysDir%\rundll32.exe %SysDir%\printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%DefaultPrinter%"
GoTo :EOF

:GetXSLDir
For %%G In (Default InstallLanguage XSLDir) Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=1,2*" %%G In ('%SysDir%\reg.exe Query
 HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language 2^>NUL ^|
 %SysDir%\findstr.exe /I "\<Default\> \<InstallLanguage\>"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%J In ('%SysDir%\findstr.exe "::%%I:" "%~f0"'
) Do Set "%%G=%%J"
If Exist "%SysDir%\wbem\%Default%\*.xsl" (Set "XSLDir=%SysDir%\wbem\%Default%\"
) Else If Exist "%SysDir%\wbem\%InstallLanguage%\*.xsl" (
    Set "XSLDir=%SysDir%\wbem\%InstallLanguage%\")
For %%G In (Default InstallLanguage) Do Set "%%G="
Exit /B

::0001:ar
::0002:bg
::0003:ca
::0004:zh-Hans
::0005:cs
::0006:da
::0007:de
::0008:el
::0009:en
::000A:es
::000B:fi
::000C:fr
::000D:he
::000E:hu
::000F:is
::0010:it
::0011:ja
::0012:ko
::0013:nl
::0014:no
::0015:pl
::0016:pt
::0017:rm
::0018:ro
::0019:ru
::001A:hr
::001B:sk
::001C:sq
::001D:sv
::001E:th
::001F:tr
::0020:ur
::0021:id
::0022:uk
::0023:be
::0024:sl
::0025:et
::0026:lv
::0027:lt
::0028:tg
::0029:fa
::002A:vi
::002B:hy
::002C:az
::002D:eu
::002E:hsb
::002F:mk
::0030:st
::0031:ts
::0032:tn
::0033:ve
::0034:xh
::0035:zu
::0036:af
::0037:ka
::0038:fo
::0039:hi
::003A:mt
::003B:se
::003C:ga
::003D:yi
::003E:ms
::003F:kk
::0040:ky
::0041:sw
::0042:tk
::0043:uz
::0044:tt
::0045:bn
::0046:pa
::0047:gu
::0048:or
::0049:ta
::004A:te
::004B:kn
::004C:ml
::004D:as
::004E:mr
::004F:sa
::0050:mn
::0051:bo
::0052:cy
::0053:km
::0054:lo
::0055:my
::0056:gl
::0057:kok
::0058:mni
::0059:sd
::005A:syr
::005B:si
::005C:chr
::005D:iu
::005E:am
::005F:tzm
::0060:ks
::0061:ne
::0062:fy
::0063:ps
::0064:fil
::0065:dv
::0066:bin
::0067:ff
::0068:ha
::0069:ibb
::006A:yo
::006B:quz
::006C:nso
::006D:ba
::006E:lb
::006F:kl
::0070:ig
::0071:kr
::0072:om
::0073:ti
::0074:gn
::0075:haw
::0076:la
::0077:so
::0078:ii
::0079:pap
::007A:arn
::007C:moh
::007E:br
::0080:ug
::0081:mi
::0082:oc
::0083:co
::0084:gsw
::0085:sah
::0086:qut
::0087:rw
::0088:wo
::008C:prs
::0091:gd
::0092:ku
::0093:quc
::0401:ar-SA
::0402:bg-BG
::0403:ca-ES
::0404:zh-TW
::0405:cs-CZ
::0406:da-DK
::0407:de-DE
::0408:el-GR
::0409:en-US
::040A:es-ES_tradnl
::040B:fi-FI
::040C:fr-FR
::040D:he-IL
::040E:hu-HU
::040F:is-IS
::0410:it-IT
::0411:ja-JP
::0412:ko-KR
::0413:nl-NL
::0414:nb-NO
::0415:pl-PL
::0416:pt-BR
::0417:rm-CH
::0418:ro-RO
::0419:ru-RU
::041A:hr-HR
::041B:sk-SK
::041C:sq-AL
::041D:sv-SE
::041E:th-TH
::041F:tr-TR
::0420:ur-PK
::0421:id-ID
::0422:uk-UA
::0423:be-BY
::0424:sl-SI
::0425:et-EE
::0426:lv-LV
::0427:lt-LT
::0428:tg-Cyrl-TJ
::0429:fa-IR
::042A:vi-VN
::042B:hy-AM
::042C:az-Latn-AZ
::042D:eu-ES
::042E:hsb-DE
::042F:mk-MK
::0430:st-ZA
::0431:ts-ZA
::0432:tn-ZA
::0433:ve-ZA
::0434:xh-ZA
::0435:zu-ZA
::0436:af-ZA
::0437:ka-GE
::0438:fo-FO
::0439:hi-IN
::043A:mt-MT
::043B:se-NO
::043D:yi-Hebr
::043E:ms-MY
::043F:kk-KZ
::0440:ky-KG
::0441:sw-KE
::0442:tk-TM
::0443:uz-Latn-UZ
::0444:tt-RU
::0445:bn-IN
::0446:pa-IN
::0447:gu-IN
::0448:or-IN
::0449:ta-IN
::044A:te-IN
::044B:kn-IN
::044C:ml-IN
::044D:as-IN
::044E:mr-IN
::044F:sa-IN
::0450:mn-MN
::0451:bo-CN
::0452:cy-GB
::0453:km-KH
::0454:lo-LA
::0455:my-MM
::0456:gl-ES
::0457:kok-IN
::0458:mni-IN
::0459:sd-Deva-IN
::045A:syr-SY
::045B:si-LK
::045C:chr-Cher-US
::045D:iu-Cans-CA
::045E:am-ET
::045F:tzm-Arab-MA
::0460:ks-Arab
::0461:ne-NP
::0462:fy-NL
::0463:ps-AF
::0464:fil-PH
::0465:dv-MV
::0466:bin-NG
::0467:fuv-NG
::0468:ha-Latn-NG
::0469:ibb-NG
::046A:yo-NG
::046B:quz-BO
::046C:nso-ZA
::046D:ba-RU
::046E:lb-LU
::046F:kl-GL
::0470:ig-NG
::0471:kr-NG
::0472:om-ET
::0473:ti-ET
::0474:gn-PY
::0475:haw-US
::0476:la-Latn
::0477:so-SO
::0478:ii-CN
::0479:pap-029
::047A:arn-CL
::047C:moh-CA
::047E:br-FR
::0480:ug-CN
::0481:mi-NZ
::0482:oc-FR
::0483:co-FR
::0484:gsw-FR
::0485:sah-RU
::0486:qut-GT
::0487:rw-RW
::0488:wo-SN
::048C:prs-AF
::048D:plt-MG
::048E:zh-yue-HK
::048F:tdd-Tale-CN
::0490:khb-Talu-CN
::0491:gd-GB
::0492:ku-Arab-IQ
::0493:quc-CO
::0501:qps-ploc
::05FE:qps-ploca
::0801:ar-IQ
::0803:ca-ES-valencia
::0804:zh-CN
::0807:de-CH
::0809:en-GB
::080A:es-MX
::080C:fr-BE
::0810:it-CH
::0811:ja-Ploc-JP
::0813:nl-BE
::0814:nn-NO
::0816:pt-PT
::0818:ro-MD
::0819:ru-MD
::081A:sr-Latn-CS
::081D:sv-FI
::0820:ur-IN
::082C:az-Cyrl-AZ
::082E:dsb-DE
::0832:tn-BW
::083B:se-SE
::083C:ga-IE
::083E:ms-BN
::083F:kk-Latn-KZ
::0843:uz-Cyrl-UZ
::0845:bn-BD
::0846:pa-Arab-PK
::0849:ta-LK
::0850:mn-Mong-CN
::0851:bo-BT
::0859:sd-Arab-PK
::085D:iu-Latn-CA
::085F:tzm-Latn-DZ
::0860:ks-Deva
::0861:ne-IN
::0867:ff-Latn-SN
::086B:quz-EC
::0873:ti-ER
::09FF:qps-plocm
::0C01:ar-EG
::0C04:zh-HK
::0C07:de-AT
::0C09:en-AU
::0C0A:es-ES
::0C0C:fr-CA
::0C1A:sr-Cyrl-CS
::0C3B:se-FI
::0C50:mn-Mong-MN
::0C51:dz-BT
::0C5F:tmz-MA
::0C6b:quz-PE
::1001:ar-LY
::1004:zh-SG
::1007:de-LU
::1009:en-CA
::100A:es-GT
::100C:fr-CH
::101A:hr-BA
::103B:smj-NO
::105F:tzm-Tfng-MA
::1401:ar-DZ
::1404:zh-MO
::1407:de-LI
::1409:en-NZ
::140A:es-CR
::140C:fr-LU
::141A:bs-Latn-BA
::143B:smj-SE
::1801:ar-MA
::1809:en-IE
::180A:es-PA
::180C:fr-MC
::181A:sr-Latn-BA
::183B:sma-NO
::1C01:ar-TN
::1C09:en-ZA
::1C0A:es-DO
::1C1A:sr-Cyrl-BA
::1C3B:sma-SE
::2001:ar-OM
::2009:en-JM
::200A:es-VE
::200C:fr-RE
::201A:bs-Cyrl-BA
::203B:sms-FI
::2401:ar-YE
::2409:en-029
::240A:es-CO
::240C:fr-CD
::241A:sr-Latn-RS
::243B:smn-FI
::2801:ar-SY
::2809:en-BZ
::280A:es-PE
::280C:fr-SN
::281A:sr-Cyrl-RS
::2C01:ar-JO
::2C09:en-TT
::2C0A:es-AR
::2C0C:fr-CM
::2C1A:sr-Latn-ME
::3001:ar-LB
::3009:en-ZW
::300A:es-EC
::300C:fr-CI
::301A:sr-Cyrl-ME
::3401:ar-KW
::3409:en-PH
::340A:es-CL
::340C:fr-ML
::3801:ar-AE
::3809:en-ID
::380A:es-UY
::380C:fr-MA
::3c01:ar-BH
::3c09:en-HK
::3c0A:es-PY
::3c0C:fr-HT
::4001:ar-QA
::4009:en-IN
::400A:es-BO
::4401:ar-Ploc-SA
::4409:en-MY
::440A:es-SV
::4801:ar-145
::4809:en-SG
::480A:es-HN
::4C09:en-AE
::4C0A:es-NI
::5009:en-BH
::500A:es-PR
::5409:en-EG
::540A:es-US
::5809:en-JO
::580A:es-419
::5C09:en-KW
::5C0A:es-CU
::6009:en-TR
::6409:en-YE
::641A:bs-Cyrl
::681A:bs-Latn
::6C1A:sr-Cyrl
::701A:sr-Latn
::703B:smn
::742C:az-Cyrl
::743B:sms
::7804:zh
::7814:nn
::781A:bs
::782C:az-Latn
::783B:sma
::783F:kk-Cyrl
::7843:uz-Cyrl
::7850:mn-Cyrl
::785D:iu-Cans
::785F:tzm-Tfng
::7C04:zh-Hant
::7C14:nb
::7C1A:sr
::7C28:tg-Cyrl
::7C2E:dsb
::7C3B:smj
::7C3F:kk-Latn
::7C43:uz-Latn
::7C46:pa-Arab
::7C50:mn-Mong
::7C59:sd-Arab
::7C5C:chr-Cher
::7C5D:iu-Latn
::7C5F:tzm-Latn
::7C67:ff-Latn
::7C68:ha-Latn
::7C92:ku-Arab
::E40C:fr-015
```

Comment: Thanks for including error handing in the script, it is a useful addition and it makes it clear to the user they have selected a value which is incorrect and to enter another value.
This file will have to run on a number of machines and it ran fine on Windows 10 but did not work on Windows 7?

Comment: @BrianK, there is a known issue with Windows 7, with regards where WMIC looks for the XSL files, it uses for formatting output, so it is likely that which is causing you a problem. To test if this is your issue, just run the following in your Command Prompt, and see what it returns: `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Printer Get Default, Name /Format:CSV`. You hadn't mentioned that this was intended for out of date/support Operating Systems, hence the fact, I didn't feel it was worth mentioning. _Other than that issue, the code should work without problems in everything from Windows Vista_.

Comment: @BrianK, to find out more about this WMIC issue please take a look, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9673057), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38433495).